# Flex advanceddatagrid show effects when tree is expanded

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, advanceddatagrid

How to tween/add effects for the action of tree expanding/collapsing in an AdvancedDataGrid in flex.

I googled a bit, searched the livedocs, but there doesn't seem to be a concrete example for the same.

Can someone shed light on this?

A code snippet might be really nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up the openEasingFunction and openDuration style tags of the AdvancedDataGrid component.  There are a number of easing effects that can be applied to groups in the grid.

That said, I seem to be having a problem with those styles in Flex 4.6.  The tween works on the first group, but not subsequent groups in the grid.